Calibration LiDAR derive DEM for flood inundation risk map
I need to create a flood model based on a LiDAR-derived Digital Elevation Model (DEM). However, I am encountering an issue:
The line dividing the DEM into two parts shows that the right side is accurate, but the left side has river elevations that are not at the lowest points, which prevents water from running off properly.
Does anyone have insights on how to address this issue?
Additionally, I do not have the source image; I only have this DEM. As a side note, when I received the DEM, it did not align with the satellite basemap, so I had to georeference it to ensure it matched correctly.




There are certain situations from which you can't recover. Bad data is, unfortunately, one of them. You need to obtain accurate data.

I know, but exclude this dem and fabdem recently, there are not other better choice. I must go on with this.
